# jQuery load function--called, but new page is not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to Javascript and jQuery. Currently, I am working with the Google Maps API to create something for class. I would like to load another HTML page from inside one of my divs, and I'm trying to use jQuery's load function to do so. I know that the function is called, but the actual page I want to load is not loading.

Here's what the "HTML" looks like (used inside a Google Maps InfoWindow):

```
var contentString = '<div id="content">' + 
    '<p>Do you want to add this pin?' +
    '<input id="submit" type="button" value="Yes" onclick="loadForm()"> <input type="button" value="No" onclick="closeInfowindow()">' + 
    '</div>';
```

Here is my function call when the button is clicked:

```
function loadForm() {
    $("#content").load("form.html", function() {
        alert( "Load was called..." );
    });
}
```

The alert shows up when I try it out, but it does not load form.html.
form.html is an html document located in the same folder with the following contents:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form name='myForm'>
        Name: <input type='text' name='name' /> <br />
        Time Planted: <input type='datetime-local' name='time' /> <br />
        Time Found: <input type='datetime-local' name='time' /> <br />
        Location: <input type='text' name='location' /> <br />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks so much in advance for your help :)

Comment: Remove the <html> and <body> tags don't need them if you loading a partial.

Comment: Hi! Do you see any errors on console?

Comment: I've removed the <html> and <body> tags. Also, sorry if this is a terrible question but--I'm not quite sure what you mean by errors on console?

Comment: If it's helpful, here is my github repo for this project: https://github.com/zhixu/Mission-2-GPS

Comment: Did you check your network traffic (in your browser console)?  Make sure you are actually requesting `mysite.com/form.html` when you click load and that the url `mysite.com/form.html` returns what you expect.  The first argument to load should be a URL and maybe you're not quite pointing to the right place.  You mentioned a "folder" - perhaps you need to fully qualify the url like `/subdir/folder/form.html`.